# Approximation: Understanding a property of continued fractions and convergents

Tags: inequality, approximation, absolute-value, continued-fractions

In a [paper](https://deweger.xs4all.nl/papers/%5B35%5DSidW-3n+1-ActaArith%5B2005%5D.pdf) by Simons & Weger in 2005, they talk about approximating the value of $\delta = \dfrac{\log3}{\log2}$ through [continued fraction theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) using integers $p$ and $q$.

Specifically, they state in (4.2):

> "Recall that we denote by $p_n/q_n$ the $n$th convergent to $\delta$. Continued fraction theory shows that convergents are best approximations, i.e. any other approximation with smaller denominator is worse.

When I read through the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fractions) on continued fractions, I am finding the following property (see Theorem 5, Corollorary 1) in [section 7.2 Some Useful Theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Some_useful_theorems):

> "A convergent is nearer to the limit of the continued fraction than any fraction whose denominator is less than that of the convergent."

Let:

- $p_n, q_n$ be the $n$th convergent for $\delta$
- $K,L$ be positive integers where $2^{K+L} > 3^K$
- $|x|$ be the [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) of $x$

Does it now follow that:

$$|(K+L) - K\delta| \ge |p_n - q_n\delta|$$

I am asking because I am trying to understand the implications of Theorem 5, Corollary 1 and trying to understand the reasoning behind Lemma 10 in the paper by Simons & Weger.

My assumption would be that:

$$|\frac{K+L}{K} - \delta| \ge |\frac{p_n}{q_n} - \delta|$$

But it is not clear to me that this would imply $|(K+L) - K\delta| \ge |p_n - q_n\delta|$.  Since $K \le q_n$, it is not clear to me that dividing the one side by $K$ will necessarily still be greater than dividing the other side by $q_n$.

I also have my doubts about how absolute values affect the equation.

Does Theorem 5, Corollary 1 from Wikipedia, combined with my assumptions, lead to this conclusion:

$$|(K+L) - K\delta| \ge |p_n - q_n\delta|$$

If yes, could you show the details of how it follows (either by formally stating the definition of Theorem 5, Corollary 1 or showing how the result derives from a formal definition).

Comment: do you have Khinchin's little book?

Comment: @willjagy I have 3 Pearls of Number Theory.  Is that the little book?

Comment: no, Continued Fractions. He says, page 24, "a best approximation of the first kind may fail to be a best approximation of the second kind"  And Theorem 16, every best approximation of the second kind is a convergent. So, some convergents work, some are not quite good enough.

Comment: @wiijagy Yes, I have that book too.  Thanks very much for the reference!  I will take a look!  :-)

Comment: here we go:  Thm 17: Every convergent is a best approximation of the second kind, the only exceptions being trivial, either integer or half integer. proof pages 26-28

Comment: When I make plots of the matter, I always include the *generalized convergents* to have more data. Perhaps it is helpful to have a short look at this.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms is that in the Khinchin book?

Comment: @Will - sorry, I don't have the book. Don't you know about the *generalized convergents*?

Comment: @Gottfried I don't know what they are; not in the Khinchin book, although I have others

Comment: If you have $p_k/q_k$, $p_{k+1}/q_{k+1}$, and $p_{k+2}/q_{k+2}$ then the generalized convergents in between are the numbers $p_k/q_k + j \cdot p_{k+1}/q_{k+1}$ for $j=1..m$ such that $p_k/q_k + (m+1) \cdot p_{k+1}/q_{k+1} = p_{k+2}/q_{k+2}$. You can see the filling out in the table under ***2.1*** in my listings http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/2hochS_3hochN_V2.htm . The pictures in the beginning only use the convergents, but in this table I've also included the generalized convergents: green filled: convergents, white filled: generalized convergents

Comment: @Gottfried, thanks. That is what is seen in Conway's Topograph construction for a quadratic irrational, in the notation of quadratic forms. I will take a look at your table...

Comment: @Will, sorry my notation was sloppy, from top of the head. The $j \cdot (...)$ must be for the numerators and denominators separately: $$ g_{k,j}= { p_k + j \cdot p_{k+1}\over q_k + j \cdot q_{k+1}}$$ where $g_{k,j}$ are the generalized convergents. (I think such sums are also called "mediants".

Comment: @Gottfried  Don't worry, that was what I thought you meant.